Why try to explain the unexplainable?
A lot of the questions that show up here are about trying to break open some or other old idea that seems unfounded and trying to 'explain' it in terms of something else that is also unfounded, but perhaps feels more satisfying. In culture, there is the tendency to explain a lot of unknowable things with ideas about God. But it all just seems like question-begging, and frankly, I feel just as hungry (or not) afterwards.
What is it that drives people to come up with yet more and more explanations that are not actually founded on anything? What stops us from just admitting, "That's all the farther" and moving on to something useful?
When I started learning about computer programming about 45 years ago, it came after some learning about electronics. So I can say that I do understand transistors, gates, CPUs, memory, network communications, databases and so on. As I write software now, I know 'enough' about the mechanics of computers and systems that I feel no need to pry in to quantum electrodynamics or string theory when I write a web application. I am satisfied about the foundation I am building on.
But some people apparently feel a terrifying gulf underneath their existence and are frantically churning out bricks and mortar to construct something to hold their lives up. Why? It's not going anywhere. Why this angst?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Should this be a Meta question? I recognize that it can be answered without Meta's framing, but maybe it would be more useful there.

That gulf you point out is called existential angst. It's there for everyone, but some people build blinders into their lives so they (hopefully) won't have to see it
One of the unbridgeable 'facts' of human life — right there along with death and taxes — is uncertainty. Things fall apart, the center cannot hold, etc, and we are often peculiarly unable to see it coming or do anything about it. Within particular, defined arenas we can compartmentalize that uncertainty: as you say, you've compartmentalized your programming skills so that uncertainty in the fundamentals of computer design won't impact your work, and that's great. But we can't compartmentalize everything that way. All sorts of things can happen:

Natural disasters (fires, tornadoes floods…)
Human made disasters (mass shootings, wars, drunk drivers, climate change, economic collapse…)
Personal disasters (infidelity or divorce, drug-addicted children, victimization, debilitating injuries…)
Diseases (plagues, cancers, genetic diseases…)

If you're fortunate, none of these will ever happen to you, and you'll go through life paying your taxes until death comes calling. If you're not so fortunate, well… then you'll have existential crises to face, and you'll feel that urge for a higher order of answers. Often the mere anticipation of these unpredictable events will lead people to existential angst and a wider search for meaning, but a lot of people choose the ultimate form of compartmentalization — telling themselves: "That stuff will never happen to me" — and effectively try to run out the game on pure luck.
Most of philosophy, religion, and other attempts to 'understand' the world are really efforts to understand our relationship to the world: to understand how we can gracefully and coherently cope with the weird curveballs that life can throw at us. They are attempts to deal, without either panicking or avoiding the potentialities of real life.

Defining an area of knowledge means we leave out the things outside of it. Hopefully we can make enough of a patchwork quilt of knowledge areas to stay warm at night (I think we've succeeded there). But trying to make a 'compartment' labeled 'everything', and then place a thing called God in charge of that seems kind of arrogant, or neurotic. Saying "I don't know" is often the only true statement we can make. Let's get used to saying it :-)

@ScottRowe: Well, you've misrepresented that a bit. Compartmentalizing means creating a box of things we can control and trying to seal up the gaps so that stuff we can't control doesn't work its way in. 'God' isn't a compartment; 'God' is an aspiration that all those things we can't control are controlled by something that (hopefully) likes us. Believing in a God is no more and no less neurotic than believing the universe is cold, mechanical, and indifferent; neuroses come from what we do with those beliefs.

It's there for everyone, but some people build blinders into their lives so they (hopefully) won't have to see it I'm not sure about that. It's an awfully sweeping generalization.

@AnoE: I'm not sure why you think that's 'awfully sweeping'… Do you think some people are immune to things like natural disasters, plagues, warfare, criminal or domestic violence, family tragedies, etc? Those are there for everyone , and any show on prime-time TV will show you that people worry about it. Or are you suggesting that no one tries to ignore the fact that these things might happen to them?

I am suggesting that the truth of the statement "everybody has existential angst, or is in denial about that" is not obviously true to me. There might well be people who do not have existential angst, even in such scenarios as you are bringing up, and not because they simply suppress the feeling. Or at the very least there may be very different levels of catastrophes required to bring up the feeling (in a debilitating fashion, which would be relevant for the question at hand).

@AnoE: Everyone is subject to the conditions that cause existential angst. It's not the case that everyone is exposed to those conditions equally, so different people will see it manifest in different strengths and different forms, and everyone copes with what they experience differently. Some people cope better, some worse, but only the enlightened (the saints, the prophets, etc.) don't feel the bite of it.

@AnoE: Poor people worry about their next meal; middle-class people worry about their car payments and mortgages; wealthy people worry about their status, power, and legacy. generous people worry about the suffering of others; selfish people worry that they are not getting as much as others. One doesn't need bombs and disasters to feel existential angst, because in the absence of big problems, little problems magnify and fill the mind.

You said, "problems magnify and fill the mind" - this might well be the answer to the question. Rumination certainly cows a lot of people :-)

@ScottRowe: I'm so sad that I herd that pun.

@TedWrigley, I am not saying that nobody is experiencing existential angst. I am saying that not necessarily every single person experiences existential angst. I am also very sure that things that induce e.a. in some do not in others. I am also sure that there are individuals out there that have an incredibly high level of tolerance before experiencing e.a.. I am not saying that all of this does not exist, just the very generalization to absolutely everybody is not clear to me.

@AnoE: I think we're just misunderstanding each other. Let me put it this way: in the fundamental case, everyone dies, everyone knows they're going to die, and no one knows for sure what it means. That is primary existential angst. One may lead a happy, secure, insulated life where that concern does not frequently rise to the fore, sure. But the end-point is there. Then there's the awareness that some event might disrupt that happiness, security, and insulation… We can plaster over that hole, but we can't even fill it, so there's always an awareness that the bottom might fall out.

Some people fear the bottom falling out and want more support underneath them than other people do. But what stops the worried from eventually getting over it, or dismissing their fear even though they can't stop having it arise? Why take it seriously or as a sign that "something must exist to make me safe"?

@ScottRowe: People still have to make choices in the absence of knowledge. Some people choose to believe in a God because it gives them a sense of security, community, and connection to the universe. Others choose not to believe in a God because it gives them a sense of independence and self-actuation. There's nothing intrinsically wrong with either choice.

People from small towns and agricultural areas tend to be more dependent on community and the vagaries of nature, and so a God often makes more sense to them (as another, greater form of community). People from cities and industrial areas tend to live more by their wits and skills, and don't find religion as appealing. There are pros and cons to each.

These are good points. I sometimes wonder if my questioning just does more rocking of the boat than rowing it.

This is a psychology question but it’s because we have an agency bias. For some reason, an explanation that involves the actions of an agent feels more satisfying than the actions of a mindless process.
This is ultimately the reason why people believe in god, spirits, or some other unknown world where a being is involved. It is more satisfying to think that some being exists for no reason rather than the universe or some other fundamentally mindless process existing for no reason.
This is likely due to evolutionary reasons since assuming an agent behind things happening was probably useful for survival. Thinking that a lion is causing a rustle in the wind may give you more time to run away and survive. This is just a theory though: I don’t think anyone knows for sure why we have this bias.

I was watching some lectures on political philosophy, provided online by a professor in an Ivy League university, and he mentioned the historical incorporation of the workmanship ideal in Christian religion and liberal political philosophy. The idea that God and Man are like a workman who creates and produces outcomes by acts of will. I do not accept most ideas of the philosophers because they fail to make the core distinction between how we experience willed agents and non-willed events of nature. Ethical and moral judgments arise as moral drama when we experience emotions and acts of will.

+1 Imagine the first human to crack open a geode revealing quartz and amethyst crystals on the inside. The crystals seem otherworldly compared to everything else.
What would be the explanation for this phenomenon? Is it so unreasonable, given the knowledge at the time, to provide a supernatural answer?

@IdiosyncraticSoul sure, given past knowledge, past speculations are somewhat understandable. But this is the present. We don't need to speculate, we can know, experiment, or move on without further thought.

This is just unfounded speculation on my part, but perhaps an agency bias comes with our sense of self and a theory of mind: the former pictures ourselves as having some agency in the world to fulfill our wishes, and other people's actions become much more explicable and predictable when one comes to the realization that other people are doing the same. Maybe all our causal reasoning is an outgrowth of an evolved predisposition towards teleological thinking?

@sdenham an agency bias makes sense for agents you can see or reason about their motives. But making up explanations is not reasoning. If a tornado kills someone and I reason that he must have deserved it for doing something bad that I don't know about, well, did the cows that also perished do something bad? The trees? Sometimes it is just 'reaching' and not an explanation.

@ScottRowe Here I am just speculating about why we have an agency bias. Having said that, while I agree that just making up explanations is not reasoning, it uses the same language as reasoning, and it sometimes feels like reasoning both to those saying it and those listening. It is not out of the question that both are the result of the same processes, just as when an LLM is hallucinating, it is using the exact same process (down to the weights) as when it makes 'sensible' responses; whether the output is one or the other is dependent on the initial conditions (the prompt and some entropy.)

@sdenham making up explanations is hypothesizing. "A space wizard did it", is a hypothesis.  That's why we test. That's why we use Occam's Razor. It isn't that we shouldn't make stuff up. It's that we need to decide what to take seriously.

@candied_orange and perhaps far more important: what not to take seriously. Things you should take seriously will probably make that known to you, but nothing arises to say, "don't bother with this".

@candied_orange I actually considered making that very point, but as space is at a premium in comments, I let it go - my hypothesis was that anyone interested in this topic would get it, and now we have evidence that at least one person did! As I have a few characters left here, I would like, for completeness' sake, to ask how one would start testing the hypothesis that a space wizard did it.

@ScottRowe a pragmatic philosophy that has been exploited with much blood. "Stop stabbing yourself. Do you accept the truth of the space wizard yet? Stop stabbing yourself."

@sdenham "Q? Is this you again?" or good old Occam's razor that says if the wizard is cagey enough to avoid taking credit we can generally disregard the theory in favor of a simpler one with the same or better predictive power without the wizard. Doesn't mean the wizard didn't do it but if the theory doesn't need the wizard and the wizard wants to left alone that badly what's the harm? "Stop stabbing yourself. Do you accept that Occam was right yet? Stop stabbing yourself."

Maybe it's not that it's "satisfying" to explain in terms of an agent, it's just "satisfying" to have any kind of explanation at all. But our large brains likely evolved to understand agents (other humans), so we might be incentivised to try to understand things that way. We can bring greater intellectual power to bear on that problem domain.

@Batperson You may be right. One of the hardest things to do is lie on your back and look at clouds and see them only as clouds.

@candied_orange Well, I don't think you are likely to find a more parsimonious "explanation" than "a wizard did it", and the possibility of there being other, truly testable hypotheses does not confer testability on it. While hypothesis-making may well require making something up, just making something up does not, in itself, amount to hypothesis-making. For a real-world example, consider Goff's claim that electrons are made of consciousness.

@sdenham oh great. So now the PETA people will want to free the power company.

@Batperson so it amounts to looking for the lost keys under the lamppost?

@ScottRowe if the keys aren't under the lamppost then you'll never find them there, but mental models don't have to be literally true to "work". E.g. gravity isn't really a force, but by thinking of it as such we can control spacecraft. Conceivably there could be a mental model that conceives of naturalistic processes as conscious agents. It might be pragmatically useful and also relatively intuitive to brains that evolved to understand agents.

@Batperson it sounds like the idea of "taking the Intentional Stance" towards someone or something: attributing agency and intentionality because it is a useful heuristic. It works with predicting the next move of a bear, but not the next move of a tornado. It works with predicting a Chess computer because humans designed them to do things a human would do. But it is a guess, not an explanation.

@ScottRowe if you see a tornado as the violence of an angry god, then you might infer that the tornado is wildly unpredictable, which would not be incorrect. In the moment, this might be easier to intuit than something abstract like chaotic pressure systems, so you get to survive another day. You mentioned looking for keys under lampposts where it is easier to see, but it might be more like seeing nails everywhere because you happen to be holding a hammer. A hammer can still be somewhat useful if you don't have a better tool at hand.


Why try to explain the unexplainable?

First, most of the time, we don't know that the unexplainable is unexplainable. We just explain what we think is explainable (putting aside for a moment the many charlatans who operate in this neighbourhood).
The motivation to explain is most plausibly the culturally determined realisation of a genetically determined capacity. We clearly have the capacity to try and give the apparent reason that we did something. This is probably the result of our capacity to introspected. To give X as the reason that justifies that we did Y, we only need to be intuitively aware that in our own mind, X seems to imply Y. Thus, our logical capacity allows us to make explicit the reasons that we seem to have.
It is then at least very plausible that social life may in some historically determined situations make elaborating on our reasons valuable. This was at least clearly the case in Ancient Greece, beginning some time before Aristotle's time. Whatever the reasons for that to happen, it worked remarkably well. Philosophers would sometimes try to find the reasons that things are as they appear to be, and this provided some impetus for the analytical tradition of Western Philosophy, which in its turn very plausibly helped the scientific idea to develop. The many impressive successes of science then further contributed to increase the cultural value of explanation.
There are many threads in this very complicated development, for example the idea of academies in Ancient Greece, or the historical development of the administration in some countries, and the accumulation of capital in economically developed countries etc., but the idea now seems entrenched in our culture that it is valuable to explain things.
This relative success may have given ideas to the charlatans preying on gullible people by peddling spurious explanations, including for, and perhaps particularly for, the unexplainable. Who is ever going to prove you wrong?

This would be the biggest first argument I'd make; you need to prove the statements in question are unexplainable.

@ConnieMnemonic Mine, too; additionally, the set of questions that are unanswerable is not static over time. With increasing knowledge, we can revisit old questions and find answers.

@ConnieMnemonic "you need to prove the statements in question are unexplainable" Why? I only assume that some facts may be unexplainable, not that we (or I) know that they are, or even which facts are unexplainable.

@Speakpigeon - If someone came to me because I held a view that might be seen as unexplainable, and asked me OPs question, my response would either be "yes, it's unexplainable, so I don't try to explain it" or it would be "you're mistaken; there's an explanation." In the end, if someone's entire argument rests on a mistaken assumption, their argument usually fails.

Also worth pointing out; on some level, everything is inexplicable; we should consider that even our most humdrum experiences defy understanding.

The difficulty with this question is drawing the line between questions we haven't found the right way to solve, and questions that are genuinely intractable.
For example, we've been trying to figure how how brains work, and how consciousness arises in them, for a long time. We know a lot about how individual brain cells work, and we know that various regions of a brain have specialised functions, but there's a huge gap between those two areas of knowledge, and we don't understand consciousness well at all.
Consciousness remains in the realm of philosophy and psychology, because we don't understand its biology. But it doesn't seem like something we should give up on understanding, does it?
It's hard to decide a problem is definitely intractable. We also tend to feel it's wrong to tell people not to think about things that interest them. So some people try, for a while, to deal with insoluble problems. This does not seem like a major problem.

I just think that after a few thousand years, it's time to give up solving something. If some specialists want to keep researching, that's fine, but for everyone else it should go to the curb.

@ScottRowe: If you tell people that something is too hard for them, some of them get cross and work harder on it. The most reliable way to learn something is too hard for you is to fail. If people won't learn from that ... they were going to end up obsessive about something anyway.

@ScottRowe This comment exudes the same intellectual laziness as the question.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica at least I'm consistent :-)

Your question, as evidenced by your example of yourself as a programmer, is asked from the perspective of an engineer. The goal of engineers is to build things that work and last; their approach to science is a very pragmatic one. The main criteria for any knowledge is its usefulness. All an engineer needs to know about anything is that it works, and you describe that stance very succinctly.
Philosophy is about the opposite of engineering. It does not have a pragmatic goal — all it seeks is gaining insights. Somebody in pursuit of new insights will not stop asking just because existing knowledge is sufficient to build stuff.

Besides, your premise is utterly wrong: That a question has been pondered for thousands of years without a result does not mean at all that it is unanswerable. At the dawn of mankind, almost nothing was understood beyond a purely pragmatic level, and everything was attributed to the divine. That state of affairs lasted from the emergence of the homo sapiens until maybe Buddha or ancient Greece, perhaps about 298,000 years (add a few hundred thousand years if you attribute that kind of thinking already to homo erectus.).
We have obviously made great progress after initially wondering about these things for a few hundred thousand years. If we are happy with our modern, technology-driven and -driving society we may actually be glad that some people didn't stop asking these questions.

Are some people driven to find answers because they feel terror at the prospect of death, or the apparent hostility of the universe toward life? What keeps them from just shrugging and getting on with the limited life that they clearly do have? Why be terrified? As an engineer, I manage to fly in airplanes and go in to tall buildings, when I know I could be killed doing so. But I'm going to die of something, and no one can predict what or when. So curling up in a ball would be a waste of opportunity. Think of 100 billion humans having been born, and half dieing from mosquito borne illness.

Your question is a mix of many questions, many levels.
Para 1
The first paragraph is the essential wish to know and is famously answered in te first line of Aristotle's metaphysics:

All men by nature desire to know...

I've heard it even stronger

Man IS a desire to understand

From this pov your question Why do men seek to know could as well be Why do men feel attracted to women (at least in some contexts)?
Well that's the way it is! And pursuing it is a contradiction of the question itself!!
Para 2
The second para is I suspect your real question: Why do ppl do bad philosophy?
But isnt that how everything human is?

good law — justice — and bad — legalism
good politics — statesmanship and bad — politickong
good music and bad
good oarents and not so good
good religion that redeems and bad that enslaves
Likewise there is philosophy and philosophology

I think you're familiar with Ecclesiastes
Para 3
Your 3rd paragraph is at a much finer grained level, what I will call strategic ignorance. Of which there are 2 variants:

Good strategic ignorance
Bad strategic ignorance.

Can these multiple levels be put together into a larger framework?
Philosophy, Science, Technology
I find Gurdjieff's 3-fold classification of philosophy, theory, practice useful. A more modern version would be philosophy, science, tech/engineering.

Technology/engineering practice is understanding at our level, as how to more than what is
Science/theory is in terms of laws, the more quantitative, the better
Philosophy is an exploration of all possibilities

Clearly getting lost in philosophy or even theoretical considerations will not allow you to finish your website project.
And yet if you would like to explore how one could perform an order of magnitude better than you are currently doing, you have to step back from your immediate project and ask theory/philosophy questions. What in CS is called paradigm questions.

Right, but if you asked a theory question for 2000 years and didn't get an answer, it's probably time for a new theory.

Isn't that what Rushi just said? @Rushi, The idea of a paradigm question sounds most interesting. Can you provide an example? Are some questions unanswerable because they presuppose a type of answer that is not available?

@PhilipRoe Not sure whether you are asking in the context of CS where the term is heavily (over)used. See and this.  Or philosophy where see eg. the 20th century Linguistic Turn. Finally note that the word ‘paradigm’ originates from Kuhn who regretted it!

Good work explicating some possibly-answerable questions from the original post, and sketching replies. I think this is the best approach, and that it can't be taken much farther without refining the question, which probably would make it another question.

Gosh, I am the King of Strategic Ignorance! Great concept. "Politely redirect the conversation" - I have run successful Meetup groups where that is basically the only thing I did the entire time. If I can redirect my thoughts, why can't other people?

In my experience, people do not try to explain the unexplainable. If they know a thing to be unexplainable, then most people tend to just mentally mark it as such and move on. What people do attempt is to explain and explore the edges around what is known and what is not known, in an attempt to further their knowledge.
There was a time when electricity was "unexplainable", but people became interested in learning more about it. As our collective knowledge spread into the previously unknown, it eventually reached the explanations, and then we have continued to question even further. So, generally, it is people being curious and perhaps having a bit of hubris, which has encouraged our explorations in to knowledge.
Of course, it would be a bit too generous to say that this is always the case. There is the other side of the coin where a person believes a thing to be true or untrue, contrary to some other party, and they have determined to find proof of their position so that they might be vindicated for holding their belief. This, too, can at times be effective, since even with less admirable incentives we might still increase our knowledge. It is just a slower process and more prone to reaching into the unexplainable. Even so, the seeker is still explaining more and more things and probably does not believe that the thing itself is unexplainable.
I do want to point out, though, that there are many things which a person, such as yourself, might believe to be unexplainable or unknowable, but which are, in fact, quite knowable. You mentioned beliefs about God, which I think is apt. I would say that while there are necessarily some things about God, assuming such exists, which we could not possibly know, there are things, at least in certain contexts, which we can know, at least as well as we can know anything. The problem that you might have noticed is that when people debate whether or not there is a god, they typically do so poorly, by debating the existence of god directly, rather than debating the point of actual divergence in their beliefs. People don't just believe or disbelieve God in a bubble or as a choice they just made one day. They do so because of what they believe about the fundamentals, which they almost never debate. This is what actually makes the argument go nowhere. Each side believes the other side to be acting from something unknowable, but thinks his own side to be knowable, but they often fail to realize it.

Yes, people not so much debating an issue as talking about different things entirely. The old: five blind men and the elephant.

Electricity never was unexplainable. Did you mean "unexplained"? I don't remember anyone ever demonstrating anything as unexplainable. Is there?

@RomainValeri Unexplanable with the existing tools and information. I am not certain that we can know that any particular thing could be confirmed to be perpetually unexplainable, and so I'm not convinced that universally unexplainable is even a coherent concept.

@DKing: information theory says randomness cannot be compressed, and by some interpretations (eg Minimum Message Length) that means it has no explanation. But for any particular data that's a provisional call: no explanation yet and we don't think there will be one.  (QM for example holds that the probabilities cannot be further known or reduced, and has survived some stringent tests.)


A lot of the questions that show up here are about trying to break open [...]

Finally, I can use my favorite quote from The Dark Tower book:

"To break is divine" - Ted Brautigan, The Dark Tower

I want to offer a more positive motivation for the desire to explain: For some people, trying to explain things is fun and an enjoyable activity. From my personal perspective, I became a research scientist because I love puzzle-solving and I grew up in an environment that supported my curiosity. I am confident that the same is more or less true for my colleagues and peers.
To reference another piece of media, my favorite scene in the recent movie Oppenheimer was the first successful test of the atomic bomb. The first reaction of the scientists to the massive and devastating explosion was to smile. That little smile of satisfaction that: "Yeah, we got it right! We solved the puzzle!" And I felt that.
